# JQM not loading sometime in phonegap page

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

One of our application have 3-4 html pages. Each page SQLite plugin is used to work with database. On deviceready, some data is fetched from the database and displayed on the page. When we are loading page-2 from page-1, sometimes second page loads properly but sometimes the JQM is not loading, and as a result no further function worked. I had put  following code at deviceready to check whether JQuery is loaded or not:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') { 
   alert('JQM not loaded');
}
```

and found that around 20% hits JQuery found undefined.

Please help to sortout this problem .

Indra Bisen

Comment: How you are going from page 2 to page 1? more code required to understand the problem.

Comment: Hi Indra, 

I made cordova setup last days for another question for loading jquery, jquery-mobile and cordova in the right order, hope this helps, further information would be helpful. (https://github.com/mboeckle/wikilocation/blob/master/assets/www/js/app.js) best M

Comment: Hi Atanu, we are going one page to another page  using window.location.assign("index.html") code. The problem is not arising always. Sometime app works fine and sometime not.